# Kendo slider background color?

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Slider. My requirement is, for every slider value changes I need to change the kendo slider background color.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the background of the slider, you can do something like:

```
$("#slider").kendoSlider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    smallStep: 1,
    largeStep: 20,
    showButtons: true,
    change: function (e) {
        var top = $("#slider").closest(".k-slider-wrap");
        if (e.value < 33) {
            $(".k-slider-track", top).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
            $(".k-slider-selection", top).css("background-color", "#ff0000");
        } else if (e.value < 66) {
            $(".k-slider-track", top).css("background-color", "#00ff00");
            $(".k-slider-selection", top).css("background-color", "#00ff00");
        } else {
            $(".k-slider-track", top).css("background-color", "#0000ff");
            $(".k-slider-selection", top).css("background-color", "#0000ff");
        }
    }
});
```

What I did is defining a slider with values between `0` and `100` and define the `change` handler to read current value (as `e.value`) and depending on the value define the background of the slide.

The important thing is:

1. `k-slider-selection` is the CSS class for the part of the slide that is selected.
2. `k-slider-track` is the CSS class of the complete slide.

Ex: if the value is 33 the slider part for 0-33 is `k-slider-selection` while the full range (0-100) is `k-slider-track`

Comment: I have the same question but I have multiple sliders on a page. Your solution will change the color of all the sliders as you are using class selectors. I want to be able to only change the color of slider that fired the change event ?

Comment: Yes, I am not using class selector **BUT** I constraining it to `top` that is `$("#slider").closest(".k-slider-wrap")` so it is limited to `#slider`.